# SQL Server 2008 - Full Text Search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table:

```
WID          WName
2          Looking for Data
6          What data is here
7          Nothing
8          Here we go again
```

I created a Full Text Catalog on the WName Column.

When I use:

```
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE CONTAINS (WorkspaceName, ' "data* here*" ') -- Nothing 
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE FREETEXT (WorkspaceName, 'data*') -- Row ID: 2,6
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE FREETEXT (WorkspaceName, 'here*')  -- Nothing 
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE FREETEXT (WorkspaceName, '*ere*')  -- Nothing 
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE FREETEXT (WorkspaceName, 'here')  -- Nothing 
SELECT * FROM Workspace WHERE FREETEXT (WorkspaceName, 'data') --Row ID: 2,6
```

These are not the results that I expected.

What I want to be able to do is:
If I had a color column with values

```
red
blue
blueberry
yellow, blue
```

I want to use a search of 'red blue' and have all of the above rows come back.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    workspace
WHERE   CONTAINS(WorkspaceName, '"red*" OR "blue*"')
```

Comment: When I enter, using my initial table:
SELECT  * FROM    
workspace WHERE   
CONTAINS(WorkspaceName, '"data*" OR "here*"')

I still only get rows 2 and 6

Why doesn't row ID 8 come back?

Comment: @Don: `here` is a stopword in `English` locale. You should create an empty stoplist (with a single space as a stopword) and recreate the index if you want everything to be indexed.

Comment: @Don - is this a question of capitalisation? Is "here" the same as "Here"?

Comment: @Chris: `FULLTEXT` searches are not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Quassnoi - thanks. @Don please disregard my comment in the light of that from @Quassnoi.

Comment: Quassnoi answered my question.
It was that here is a stop word and that is why I was not seeing what I was expecting.
And I was just making up strings.
Thanks